# What does ONE modify here?

Tags: possessives

**Last week he visited one of the Americans' conferences.**

Does one modify "Americans" or "conferences" or either?

Does it mean: one conference run by the Americans OR conferences run by one of the Americans?

Comment: Just asking, but wouldn't the meaning be clearer if it was rewritten as "*Last week he attended an American conference*”? Why is there an apostrophe after the "s"? Do all conferences held in the US belong to American citizens?

Comment: @Mari-LouA He does say possessive in the question. It would be possessive now...attend a conference, not visit.

Comment: Be sure to add the source for this text.  It is rather an odd way to write.  "One" is not a modifier, it heads a phrase.

Comment: @Lambie the question was edited and clarified after I posted my comment. My suggestion "Last week he attended one of the American conferences" The word "American" modifies conferences.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OP seems to be confused. I don't think we even know what  s/he means. Colin Fine interpreted it as I did. Why would yours be "better"? It's just different than the possessive.

Comment: Because  "…attended an American conference" is not ambiguous

Comment: It's *very* clumsy phrasing for any normal context, so rather than worry about what it *might* mean (one of multiple conferences associated with *one context-specific group* of Americans) you should focus on learning how to avoid coming out with such usages yourself.

Comment: It would be great if this OP would tell us exactly what they are trying to say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is formally ambiguous.

In practice, your first interpretation is almost certainly the intended one, unless the context has already established that there are several Americans involved who run (separate) conferences.

But

> One of my friends' books

is ambiguous in this way, and may remain so even when there is some context.

Comment: What does "My friends' books" have to do with "One of my friends' books"?

Comment: @user1425  my friend's books and my friends' books are pronounced the same way.

Comment: It's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> *Last week he visited* [*one of the Americans' conferences*].

"One" doesn't modify anything. Its function is that of **head** of the bracketed noun phrase.

The preposition phrase "of the Americans" then functions as complement of the head, and the whole NP is object of "visited".

The natural interpretation, I think, is that there were a number of the Americans' conferences and last week he visited one of them.